# Wpf button focus is not set when using InputBindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, inputbinding

I have the following code:

```
<Button Focusable="True">             
  <Button.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" />
    <MouseBinding Gesture="CTRL+LeftClick" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedWithCtrlCommand}" />
  </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

the view model is like this

```
public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand { get; }
public ICommand ButtonClickedWithCtrlCommand { get; }
...
{
   ButtonClickedCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { });
   ButtonClickedWithCtrlCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { });
}
```

Now if I click the button, the command is correctly executed. But somehow the focus of the button does not get set. Can someone tell me why?

It seems that the Command prevents the base functionality of the click (like the button down visalization as well). Is there a way to invoke that when using InputBindings?

PS: I know that I can achieve the same with behaviors and "event to command binding" (in fact that's how I fixed it). Maybe I'm abusing the input binding and I should not use it in the first place for "things" which are already bound (like click etc.)?

Comment: Why don't you use the Command property of the Button?: `<Button Focusable="True" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" />`. Do you get the same results then?

Comment: I need to have different commands when clicking the button with modifiers (None, CTRL, SHIFT)

Comment: You are just using a MouseBinding with a Gesture of LeftClick in your example?

Comment: True, I did not want to put more details then necessary, sorry for missing that detail. I changed the samle code

Comment: What about people who don't use a mouse?  There are more ways to invoke a button than a left click.

Comment: Well, if the button has the focus I would expect to do the simple click with space (like in normal applications)

Comment: @derape You don't have an input binding for that.  What about access keys?  What about touch input?  You're coupling too tightly to the input method.  Maybe it would be easier to use `Command` and just check the modifier keys when the command is invoked?

Comment: Can that be achieved through view model only? I would like to avoid code behind...
Also I would like to know what the input binding override that default behavior. I can't find anything in the documentation